# Writing a dynamic UNION ALL MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following list of pet types:

```
['mammal', 'fish', 'amphibian', 'reptile']
```

Currently, I'm using the following MySQL statement to generate a table from my pet types:

```
SELECT 'mammal' AS petType UNION ALL
SELECT 'fish' UNION ALL
SELECT 'amphibian' UNION ALL
SELECT 'reptile' UNION ALL;
```

The result is:

```
+-------------+
| petType     |
+-------------+
| mammal      |
| fish        |
| amphibian   |
| reptile     |
+-------------+
```

How can I change my query to accommodate a dynamic list of pet types. For example, does MySQL have some kind of for loop that would allow me to say:

```
for pet in my_list_of_pet_types:
    SELECT pet + "UNION ALL"
```

Comment: Would you please expand on what you mean by dynamic list? You have one table of "petType" and all the pets are in there. What do wish to accomplish?

Comment: A list that is subject to change.

Comment: What triggers the change? If you have a table of "petType" and they all have mammal, fish, amphibian and reptile and you are pulling all these values, what happens that you need something different?

Comment: I do not have a table of pet types. Rather, I generate a table of pet types from a list given to me by the user of my application.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the users enter data in your application (this data is stored somewhere) and you pull 4 database and you UNION them all. Now, you want this list to be different every time they enter values? If that is the case, you can just store the result of your UNION into a table and INSERT (the new data) and TRUNCATE the previous ones.

Comment: Based on your previous questions from last week, this is beginning to sound like it's turning into an XY Problem. http://xyproblem.info/  I would suggest that you create a new question, start all the way at the beginning and explain what exactly it is that you are trying to accomplish. With some example data and expected output. We gave you some suggestions that solved the questions asked and pointed out some of the potential pitfalls of what you said you were trying to do. Since this is now the 6th post on this topic, I'm assuming that there's a bit more to the full problem.

Comment: And that came out a bit harsher than I intended, so I do apologize for that. So... these values are dynamic pet types provided from a Python free-form input, correct? And you want to compare them to a massive list of internal pet types that are currently in your database , correct?

Comment: you are correct.

Comment: Staying within the scope of this question, I simply want to SELECT from a dynamic list provided by the user, creating a temporary, one-column table from those values. Sample output is above.

Comment: I would still say that allowing free-form entry for this search data has a huge potential for bad results or abuse. Plus, I also think that a search with no pet type results would best be handled in the application itself. You can't `JOIN` on a record that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Shawn. OP, given the additional information, Shawn has the best answer. Since these are data entered by users that aren't in a db yet, you can't compare them via SQL. You need a front end process where it compares the DB to what the user enters.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You use UNION when you wish to combine the same columns from another table

SELECT delivery_name, delivery_date FROM home_deliveries
UNION ALL
SELECT delivery_name, delivery_date FROM commercial_deliveries

I am not sure if what you are doing is the right way to solve your problem. Further detail of the problem you are trying to solve would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pet AS petType FROM my_list_of_pet_types
ORDER BY pet
```

Comment: In what format does my_list_of_pet_types need to be? MySQL is throwing an error when I attempt to select from a tuple.

Comment: @Brinley, BWS means that you could grab the petType values directly from the existing data (which is stored in the "my_list_of_pet_types" table if such exists). If it doesn't exist, maybe it's time to create such?)

Comment: My application works in such a way that my_list_of_pet_types can't already exist as a table. Rather, I get a list a pet types from a user, which I then use to create a temporary table.